# Twitter access behind a proxy

Tags: twitter, proxy

We're forced to use a proxy server for internet and LAN connections in our company and they've recently blocked Twitter. I use Twitter for my work as I follow many well known people from the software development industry and even have a [list](http://twitter.com/funky_rus/list/geeks) setup for that.

The **question is how can I access tweets from this list** on my machine now?

All of the public (web) proxies, VPN etc. are also blocked, hence it has to be some kind of **cloud service**, which fetches the tweets for me to read them.

I've been using *Google Reader* with *twiterlist2rss* until it broke: http://twiterlist2rss.appspot.com/funky_rus/lists/geeks/statuses.rss (400: rate limit problems). It's been down for more than a week now, so I lost my faith in it and looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Google should help you here
Open Google, type in all the names in this fashion

**twttrusr1 or twttrusr2 or hckrboy42**

then select option *latest* from left hand navigation under the *more* option
You will have a live stream of all your twitter feeds

p.s: do not try to bypass your company's proxy/firewall , it will just jeopardize the security measures taken by them.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up of my post on superuser. Since IP addresses access does not work, have you the possibility to set up a proxy? I mean have a PC that can run a SSH server for example? If yes, you can use it as SOCKS proxy with `-D` option.

BTW: @Shark is right, security measure are here for a reason. Did you try to talk to IT people about your problem?

Comment: thanks, I though about seting up a proxy on my home machine and go online through with some sort of encryption but that's too much hassle. I'm really looking for some sort of cloud service like I said. Google's "latest" search results is an option, but not for the whole twitter list. The reason it's blocked is not a security measure, they just want to apply same rules for all job rules so they have less maintenance work to do. It's just the negatives of the corporate world, just like in Dilbert comics.